# Huawei map do not render

Tags: flutter, huawei-map-kit

I implement Huawei map in flutter project. But i have error when I open map i see white screen with marker. [image]

```
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678): cache error trace log : ErrorTraceLogDTO{ scenario = ACCESS_SERVICE_ERROR', message='6 : REQUEST_DENIED'}
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678): com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.ClientAccessException: * * *E*U*S*_*E*I*D
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.ClientAccessException$Builder.build(Unknown Source:25)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.mab.a(Unknown Source:20)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.mab.d(Unknown Source:86)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.mab.a(Unknown Source:111)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.mab.a(Unknown Source:1)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.provider.client.dataversion.maa.n(Unknown Source:2)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.provider.client.dataversion.maa.lambda$jcQ1fGjHHpJyaDde0F9VW2PoUFA(Unknown Source:0)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.provider.client.dataversion.-$$Lambda$maa$jcQ1fGjHHpJyaDde0F9VW2PoUFA.call(Unknown Source:4)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.mab$maa.a(Unknown Source:3)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.provider.client.dataversion.maa.e(Unknown Source:28)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.provider.client.dataversion.maa.d(Unknown Source:4)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.provider.cache.mae$maa.a(Unknown Source:0)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at com.huawei.hms.maps.provider.cache.mae$maa.call(Unknown Source:0)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at mvb.b(Unknown Source:17)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at mtm.a(Unknown Source:14)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at mvg$mab.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at mtp$maa.run(Unknown Source:9)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at mvu.run(Unknown Source:13)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at mvu.call(Unknown Source:0)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_8(12678):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

To init map i use

```
HuaweiMapInitializer.initializeMap();
HuaweiMapInitializer.setApiKey(apiKey: 'api_key');
```

Dependencies version:

```
Huawei map: 6.5.0+301
com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.7.2.300
com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.7.3.300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message you received and the Map Kit documentation, your api key might be invalid.

```
ACCESS_SERVICE_ERROR', message='6 : REQUEST_DENIED'
```

According to the Map Kit [FAQ](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/faq-0000001050166999#section9358141913329):

"Why is error code 6 returned when the web API is called? The possible cause is that the API key contains special characters. You need to encode the special characters using encodeURI. For example, if the original API key is ABC/DFG+, the conversion result is ABC%2FDFG%2B."

Comment: Ye, my api key wa wrong, but i don't need using encodeURI. But i has wrong signingConfigs in app/build.gradle